# How to install the PHP/Serialization module in Perl?

Tags: php, perl

When running nfsen, my logs display:

```
nfsen[24213]: ERROR: Can't locate PHP/Serialization.pm in @INC (you may need to install the PHP::Serialization module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/nfsen/plugins /usr/local/nfsen/libexec /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /usr/local/nfsen/plugins/Events.pm line 84.#012BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/nfsen/plugins/Events.pm line 84.#012Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/nfsen/libexec/Nfcomm.pm line 514.
```

Is there an easy way to install the Serialization module separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `PHP/Serialization.pm` or better `/usr/share/perl5/PHP/Serialization.pm` is part of the package `libphp-serialization-perl`.

Therefore install via

```
sudo apt-get install libphp-serialization-perl
```